# I don't know how to use \ref

Tags: hyperref, ref

I want know how to use \ref. I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Welcome to the \label{here}reference
\newpage
go to reference~\ref{here} on page 1
\end{document}
```

Thanks for help me.

Comment: `\label` records the last referencable thing, most numbered constructs may be referenced but there there is nothing, put `\section{zzzz}` before it then the `\ref` will produce **1** the section number

Comment: Can you put that in my code please, I don't understand you. Thanks

Comment: A good introduction can be found at [LaTeX Wikibooks: Labels and Cross-referencing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing), especially the first example in their [Examples](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing#Examples) section.

Comment: What do you want your second page to read? `go to reference ... on page 1`? What should .... be? The page number? Or a link to the first page?

Comment: @samcarter I want to go to the word:reference(on page 1)

Comment: @Solid Try `\hyperlink{here}{go to reference on page 1}`

Answer (score 3):

I try to make up something from the comments and your answers to them, maybe it's what you want:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Start}
Welcome to the \label{here}reference
\newpage
\section{Mid}
go to reference in section~\ref{here} on page~\pageref{here}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like:

[image: page]

Basically a `\ref` is always referencing towards the counter of the chapter/section/subsection/... while a `\pageref` is referencing to the page the label is on. `hyperref` also has an `\autoref` which has some standard names for chapter/section/subsection, so you can leave that part out of writing.